# How install Drupal on SSD on Linux

Tags: installation

I have an installed SSD on my Ubuntu Linux machine. It's blank, partitioned, and formatted. I'd like to install my Drupal sites on it so I can work on them locally there. However, the only way I've found to install Drupal so far on Ubuntu is in the /var/www/html folder (and only 1 site there at a time at that).

Anyone have a suggestion (or a tutorial! - dare to dream) for installing multiple Drupal 7 sites on a SSD on Ubuntu Linux for local development?

Answer (score 1):

You can do many things to fix this.

1. Delete the /var/www/html directory. Create a symlink from your SSD to the location.

   $ rm -rf /var/www/html && ln -s /media/ssd/document_root /var/www/html
2. Modify your web servers configuration to use the SSD as the document root.
3. Create a virtual host for your webserver and point it at the SSD. Edit. I just saw youur previous question. Copy your 000-default.conf to 25-example.com.conf and alter the document root and directory durectives. Don't forget to restart apache.

Are you using stock Apache? What version of Ubuntu?